# How to reduce gas cost in polygon function

Tags: blockchain, solidity

I have a Smart contract made in polygon.

In this contract, i have a function for voting:

```
function voteForCandidate(string[] calldata names, string[][] calldata vote ) public returns (bool){//bytes32[] memory  whatsapps
  require(owner == msg.sender, "Only owner can call this function");
  string memory artistas;
  for(uint i = 0; i < vote.length; i++) {
    artistas = "[";
    for(uint y = 0; y < vote[i].length; y++)
    {  
       artistas = append(artistas, " , ", vote[i][y]);
       votesReceived[vote[i][y]] += 1;         
    }
     artistas = append(artistas, " ] ", "");
    emit Vote(names[i], artistas);
}
return true;
```

}

I group transaction in lots of 100, so this foor lopp wil run 100 times and emit 100 events.
This is great for what i need to show for the users. But i had paid a lot of gas: (see image)
[I am using 500 GWEi of gasprice becuse matic gast track is change everytime and if use a low gas price, sometimes i got transaction underpriced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXdQw.png)

Any idea to reduce gas cost?

Comment: Before giving you an answer, you need to explain us what you want to do. To me looks like you want to record votes on chain, but all the votes come from the same account (`owner`). Is that right?
Do you really need to emit 1 event for each vote received, if all the votes come from the same account? Cannot you just publish a combined version of the votes (i.e. # of votes per artist), and emit an Event with the total # of votes received by artist? That would be more scalable IMHO

Comment: your append function will also use a lot of gas. Do you really need to do that?